# JPA not removing entity

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to remove entity but for some reason it doesn't work. I there were similar questions, but they were usually related to cascade removal and @OneToMany relations. This is not the case here. What is more, I've based this code on already existing one in another package that works perfectly. I have no idea why this repository is making problems. I'm using PostgreSQL database if it matters.

The service class:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CampaignService {

    private final CampaignRepository campaignRepository;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Transactional
    public Long deleteCampaign(UUID campaignToDeleteId, String username) {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Campaign was not found"));

        return campaignRepository.removeByIdAndUserId(campaignToDeleteId, user.getId());
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface CampaignRepository extends JpaRepository<Campaign, UUID> {

    Long removeByIdAndUserId(UUID id, Long userId);

}
```

And the entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Campaign {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID id;

    private Long userId;

    private String name;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private CalendarSystem calendarSystem;
    private Instant campaignDateTimeStart;
    private Instant campaignDateTimeCurrent;
    private LocalDate realDateStart;
    private LocalDate realDateLastPlayed;

}
```

**EDIT:**
For some reason, the `remove` method is executing SELECT, and when I switch to `delete`, nothing is shown in the DEBUG logs, as if nothing is being executed. I've changed the repository method to use @Modifying and @Query annotations. However, I feel like I shouldn't have to do this. Why does it have to be this way while I didn't have to do it in the other repositories?

That's how it looks like right now:

```
@Modifying
@Query("delete from Campaign c where c.id = :id and c.userId = :userId")
int removeByIdAndUserId(UUID id, Long userId);
```

Analogical, working example:
Entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Note {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private UUID campaignId;
    private String title;
    private String body;

}
```

Service method:

```
@Transactional
public Long deleteNote(long id) {
    return noteRepository.removeById(id);
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface NoteRepository extends JpaRepository<Note, Long> {

    List<Note> findAllByCampaignId(UUID campaignId);
    Long removeById(long id);

}
```

There's a "relation" to Campaign, but there's no Hibernate annotation yet so I don't think it matters. Can the problem be related to the type of ID being used? the `Note` has ID of type long while `Campaign` has ID of type `UUID`.

Comment: Is there an error while executing? How do you know it is not working? You could try to enable SQL logging to see what queries are issued to the database with something like `logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG`

Comment: You're right, there's something wrong with it. When I'm logging the "remove" methods, it uses SELECT instead of DELETE. When i switched to "deleteById", it logs nothing at all